# Liferay - Scheduler not triggering at the given time

Tags: java, cron, liferay, scheduler

I have been trying to implement a scheduler job in Liferay. My controller looks like shown below.

```
public class MyController {
@RenderMapping
    public String defaultView() {
        String cron = "0 0 11 1/1 * ? *";
        Date dt = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dt); 
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

        Trigger trigger = null;  
        try {  
            trigger = TriggerFactoryUtil.buildTrigger(TriggerType.CRON, Scheduler.class.getName(), Scheduler.class.getName(), calendar.getTime(), null, cron);  
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        Portlet portlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById("portlet_id");  
        Message message = new Message();  
        message.put("CONTEXT_PATH", portlet.getContextPath());  
        message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, Scheduler.class.getName());  
        message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portlet.getPortletId());  

        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, scheduler);
        try {  
            SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule( trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, "", DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, message, 5);  
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        return "view";
    }
}
```

The `Scheduler` class is defined as follows

```
public class Scheduler implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
        myMethodAtScheduledTime();
    }

    public void myMethodAtScheduledTime() {
        System.out.println("Invoked at " + new Date());
    }
}
```

I did not provide the cron time in `liferay-portlet.xml` as I need it to be configured by the user. So for testing, I set the cron time to trigger at a 11.00 every day.

But, even though I set my cron time to 11.00am, the job starts the next second itself (even before 11.00) and it never ends. It keeps on getting invoked every 10-20 seconds. I want to restrict the job invocation exactly to 11.00 and it should run only once. What is the mistake am I doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I am not really sure where the mistake was. But when I replaced the following code instead of the above controller code, I was able to trigger the scheduler at the exact time.

```
public class MyController {
@RenderMapping
    public String defaultView() {
        try {
            String cron = "0 0 11 1/1 * ? *";
            String description = "";
            String destinationName = DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH;
            int exceptionsMaxSize = 0;
            String portletId = "portlet_id";

            Message message = new Message();
            message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, Scheduler.class.getName());            
            message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portletId);

            Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(Scheduler.class.getName(), Scheduler.class.getName(), cron);
            SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, description, destinationName, message, exceptionsMaxSize);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "view";
    }
}
```

The issue should be either that I was making the wrong `Trigger` object or a wrong invocation of `registerMessageListener` method.

Answer (score 0):

Also this url, can get more details about the scheduler

http://liferaytutorial.blogspot.in/2014/07/creating-scheduler-dynamically-in.html

Comment: The comments below this blog was written by me :-)